# Working Through a Quantstat Example Yields Error

Tags: r, quantstrat

I'm trying to work through an example (https://statsmaths.github.io/stat395-f17/assets/final_project/amarnani.html) of quantstrat: A Brief Introduction to Quantitative Trading and the Quanstrat [sic] Library by Dhiraj Amarnani
November 29, 2017, but am getting an error.

I've tried finding undefined variables; for example "strategy" is defined, but "portfolio" is not.  I'm not experienced enough to troubleshoot further.
I've posted an issue on Github.  I'm also working through a course on quantstrat on DataCamp, but have not been able to figure out the problem.  Finally, I have searched Stack Overflow; there are other quantstrat examples, but this one (although it is much referenced otherwise) is not cited here.

```
library(devtools)
library(quantmod)
library(quantstrat)
library(TTR)
library(png)
library(IKTrading)
```

## _________SETUP___________

```
rm(list = ls(.blotter), envir = .blotter)

initdate <- "2010-01-01"
from <- "2011-01-01" #start of backtest
to <- "2017-01-01" #end of backtest
Sys.setenv(TZ= "EST") #Set up environment for timestamps

currency("USD") #Set up environment for currency to be used

symbols <- c("AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG", "FB", "TWTR", "AMZN", "IBM") #symbols used in our backtest
getSymbols(Symbols = symbols, src = "google", from=from, to=to, adjust = TRUE) #receive data from google finance,  adjusted for splits/dividends

stock(symbols, currency = "USD", multiplier = 1) #tells quanstrat [sic] what instruments present and what currency to use

tradesize <-10000 #default trade size
initeq <- 100000 #default initial equity in our portfolio

strategy.st <- portfolio.st <- account.st <- "firststrat" #naming strategy, portfolio and account

# removes old portfolio and strategy from environment
rm.strat(portfolio.st)
rm.strat(strategy.st) 

# initialize portfolio, account, orders and strategy objects
initPortf(portfolio.st, symbols = symbols, initDate = initdate, currency = "USD")
initAcct(account.st, portfolios = portfolio.st, initDate = initdate, 
currency = "USD", initEq = initeq)
initOrders(portfolio.st, initDate = initdate)
strategy(strategy.st, store=TRUE)
```

## _________Indicators___________

```
# graphs creation code excluded here

add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
          name = 'SMA',
          arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=200),
          label = 'SMA200')
add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
          name = 'SMA',
          arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=50),
          label = 'SMA50')
add.indicator(strategy = strategy.st,
          name = 'RSI',
          arguments = list(price = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=3),
          label = 'RSI_3')
```

## ____________Signals___________

```
# graphs creation code excluded here

#First Signal: sigComparison specifying when 50-day SMA above 200-day SMA
add.signal(strategy.st, name = 'sigComparison',
      arguments = list(columns=c("SMA50", "SMA200")),
      relationship = "gt",
      label = "longfilter")

#Second Signal: sigCrossover specifying the first instance when 50-day SMA
# below 200-day SMA 
add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigCrossover",
       arguments = list(columns=c("SMA50", "SMA200")),
       relationship = "lt",
       lablel = "sigCrossover.sig")

#Third Signal: sigThreshold which specifies all instance when RSI is below 20 (indication of asset being oversold)
add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigThreshold",
       arguments = list(column = "RSI_3", threshold = 20,
                        relationship = "lt", cross = FALSE),
       label = "longthreshold")

#Fourth Signal: sigThreshold which specifies the first instance when rsi is above 80 (indication of asset being overbought)
add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigThreshold",
       arguments = list(column = "RSI_3", threshold = 80,
                        relationship = "gt", cross = TRUE),
       label = "thresholdexit")

#Fifth Signal: sigFormula which indicates that both longfilter and longthreshold must be true.
add.signal(strategy.st, name = "sigFormula",
       arguments = list(formula = "longfilter & longthreshold",
                        cross = TRUE),
      label = "longentry")
```

## ________________Rules________________

```
#The first rule will be an exit rule. This exit rule will execute when the market environment is no longer conducive to a trade (i.e. when the SMA-50 falls below SMA-200)
add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
     arguments = list(sigcol = "sigCrossover.sig", sigval = TRUE,
                      orderqty = "all", ordertype = "market",
                      orderside = "long", replace = FALSE,
                      prefer = "Open"),
     type = "exit")

#The second rule, similar to the first, executes when the RSI has crossed above 80. 
add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
     arguments = list(sigcol = "thresholdexit", sigval = TRUE,
                      orderqty = "all", ordertype = "market",
                      orderside = "long", replace = FALSE,
                      prefer = "Open"),
     type = "exit")

#Additionally, we also need an entry rule. This rule executes when 
# longentry is true (or when long filter and longthreshold are true). 
# That is when SMA-50 is above SMA-200 and the RSI is below 20.
add.rule(strategy.st, name = "ruleSignal",
     arguments = list(sigcol = "longentry", sigval = TRUE,
                      orderqty = 1, ordertype = "market",
                      orderside = "long", replace = FALSE,
                      prefer = "Open", osFUN = IKTrading::osMaxDollar,
                      tradeSize = tradesize, maxSize = tradesize),
     type = "enter")
```

## ______________Performance Analsis_________________

```
# Here is the code that didn't work (first line): 

out <- applyStrategy(strategy = strategy.st, portfolios = portfolio.st)
updatePortf(portfolio.st)
daterange <- time(getPortfolio(portfolio.st)$summary)[-1]

updateAcct(account.st, daterange)
updateEndEq(account.st)



# Error in `dimnames<-.xts`(`*tmp*`, value = dn) : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
# In addition: Warning messages:
# 1: In match.names(columns, colnames(data)) :
# all columns not located in SMA50 SMA200 for AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low 
# AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
# 2: In min(j, na.rm = TRUE) :
# no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
# 3: In max(j, na.rm = TRUE) :
# no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
# 4: In min(j, na.rm = TRUE) :
# no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
# 5: In max(j, na.rm = TRUE) :
# no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
# 6: In match.names(column, colnames(data)) :
# all columns not located in RSI_3 for AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low 
# AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted longfilter sigCrossover.sig
# 7: In min(j, na.rm = TRUE) :  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
# 8: In max(j, na.rm = TRUE) :  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question; starting with my objective, which was to get an example of quantstrat running so that I could gradually make changes to conform to our team's trading strategy.  Disappointed that I couldn't make the example cited above work (and also that I got no bites on Stack Overflow), I finally found a course on DataCamp called "Financial Trading in R" which explains the quantstrat package in very simple bites.  It seems clear to me that the example I've cited here seems to be taken from that course.  I attempted unsuccessfully to run quantstrat from the DataCamp slides, but was able to get quantstrat working using the examples in the course.  Highly recommended.  Glad to pass along the R code if anyone is interested.